# Svelte Browser refresh issue

Tags: svelte

I have an issue with my svelte site, when I deploy a production version of it, then I need the either open the site in incognito or clean my browser's cache, to see the changes.

Anyone that knows a solution or workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Open site with enabled dev console and check "Disable cache"

[image: disable cache]